# A question about self-reference

Tags: logic, type-theory

Let $\textsf{Prop}$ denote the universe of propositions and let $A:\textsf{Prop}$. Now, consider $(\star)$:
$$A\leftrightarrow\exists X:\textsf{Prop}.(X\rightarrow A)\wedge X\tag{$\star$}$$
It is easy to show that ($\star$) is a theorem. But my question is, since $\exists X:\textsf{Prop}.(X\rightarrow A)\wedge X$ is itself a proposition, namely, $\exists X:\textsf{Prop}.(X\rightarrow A)\wedge X:\textsf{Prop}$, shall we let $X=\exists Y:\textsf{Prop}.(Y\rightarrow A)\wedge Y:\textsf{Prop}$ such that $X$ is a proposition that entails $A$ and that is true? I think it is possible but it runs into a problem of self-reference. Is there any way to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's not a problem, we just have $A\leftrightarrow \exists X:{\rm Prop}.(X\to (\exists Y:{\rm Prop}.(Y\to A)\land Y))\,\land X$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4015513/a-question-about-self-reference

Comment: @Berci Hi, maybe  I didn't express myself in a clear way. Yes, we can have that but my question is how to avoid this if possible. Because that would always give a very long proposition by replacing a new variable with a similar forumla.

Comment: @RobPratt Hi, it seems that your link relates my question to my question itself. A joke???:-)

Comment: @ferdinand Yes.

Comment: It depends on the rules of type theory you use. If you have impredicative Prop then the formula in question defines a proposition in Prop. Otherwise, well, you may not even have a well formed formula, or the formula is well formed but does not define a proposition in Prop, or whatever.